# How to fix this specific “TypeError: 'str' object is not callable” error in Python? (Beginner Question)

Tags: python, input

Can't seem to find the error in this code.
Appreciate any help I can get.

```
    x = input("Enter the price of AAPL stock today: ")
    x = int(x)
    y = input("Enter the number of APPLE stocks that you want to buy: ")
    y = int(y)
    print('The total funds required to buy {} shares of AAPL stock at {} 
    dollars is {}'.format(y, x, x*y))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using multiple `.format()` print. Use index of variable like:

```
print("...{0}...{1}..{3}..{n}".format(a,b,c,...,n))
```

According to your image check your code and output below:

```
x=int(input("Enter the price of APPL stock today: "))
y=int(input("Enter the number of APLE stocks that you want to buy: "))
print("The total funds required to buy {0} shares of APPL stock at {1} dollars is {2}".format(x,y,x*y))
```

Output

```
Enter the price of APPL stock today: 20
Enter the number of APLE stocks that you want to buy: 30
The total funds required to buy 20 shares of APPL stock at 30 dollars is 600
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are missing {0}, {1} and {2}, in the string that you are outputting.